# Colonists land on a new planet, plants turn out to be toxic

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to find a book where colonists land on a new planet but the food supply / plants turn out to be toxic to people. In the end the people realize the plants aren't actually toxic, but extremely concentrated with healthy minerals - and if they dilute them, the plants are very healthy and nutritious.

[edits added]: this book was read in the early 90s or late 80s so it is not Orson Scott Card's Pathfinder (from 2010) or The Green Book - which had glass like plants, not 'toxic' plants which were just super concentrated nutrients. Thanks for your help so far everybody, but we're still looking for the answer.

Comment: Do you remember when or where you first read this book? Or what form the book was published in (e.g. part of an anthology, red hardback)?

Comment: I read the book in the late 80s or early 90s. Unfortunately I can't remember much else.

Comment: Pretty sure it was a child or young adult that figured it out and saved the day.

Comment: And it's not The Green Book BTW which had plants that were glass or crystals that just needed to be ground up - this definitely had super concentrated nutrients.

Comment: In Orson Scott Card's "Pathfinder," human colonists inhabit a planet with toxic plants. I don't remember if the second part applies or not.

Comment: Thanks - not the Green Book and not Pathfinder - still looking for answer - thanks everybody for your help though.

Comment: Hm. There's a humerus short story about the reverse, where a batallion crashlands on a planet and must survive until rescue. The food is killing the men but they are starving. Turns out the food is lacking certain essential vitamins or something, and one paranoid soldier who makes his own medicines is the hero of the corp.

Comment: Humerous. Thanks autocorrect >.<

Comment: The typo is still humorous, even after correcting the autocorrect. :-)

Comment: @Broklynite, that sounds like Cum Grano Salis by Randall Garrett.  All the fruit has a strong chelating agent that pulls the iron out of blood cells, but is rendered harmless by the magnesium in the paranoid guy's stomach pills.

Answer (score 5):

*[The Faces of Ceti](https://www.buffalolib.org/vufind/Record/628567/Reviews)* by Mary Caraker

> Arriving at the Tau Ceti system they intend to colonize, 500 Earth pioneers are surprised to find not one, but two habitable planets. An ideological rift between them suggests a division of the colonists, and the absorbing plot follows the struggle for survival on the smaller planet, surrounded by harsh conditions, poisonous plants, and the native, possibly intelligent, hlur. These are interesting animals, something like burbling kangaroos, and the question of whether they are sentient fuels a heated debate about killing and eating them in the face of a severe food shortage. Teenagers Maya and Brock risk their lives to discover the secret of the hlur and why they can eat the indigenous plants when earthlings cannot.

Comment: This sounds like it might be it. The nature of the "secret of the hlur" they discover would be the most relevant piece of information.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they learn how to treat and eat the plants.

Comment: If you've actually read this book, mentioning that in your answer would help assure voters that it's actually a match.

Answer (score 3):

There is a partial match between the description of the story as given in the question and my recollection of the short story ["Hunter, Come Home"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58489) by Richard McKenna. (1963)

(Which is, by the way, said to be the original inspiration for the Avatar movies.)

A plot synopsis can be found here: https://numinousbookofreview.blogspot.com/2015/08/hunter-come-home-by-richard-mckenna.html -- It starts with some details that are unsuitable for a synopsis, and ends prematurely, presumably so as not to give away any spoilers, so it is a good synopsis in this regard.

It has also been given as an answer to [another question here on scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211820/163821)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes or matching details from the question, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @fez I just found a link to isfdb.org, so I added it. The avatar inspiration claim is just something I stumbled upon, I cannot support it. What else can I do to improve the answer?

Comment: Looking into it...

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to isfdb! If there is a plot synopsis available, it wouldn't hurt to add that in too :) welcome to SciFi.SE!

Comment: @fez I think I have done my best now.